# What is this Arial looking font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I've been trying to compare this font, with an online photo editor called pixlr but no luck.

What is the name of the font on this picture? It's a little bit transparent, it has a **metro** word.

[image]

Comment: We have a lot of resources for font-finding. Please try these, and if still no luck, edit your answer and let us know what you have tried. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 1):

You may use www.myfonts.com to look for it.

Suggested by the site, it is Regan from The Northern Block Regan.

Or you may access the results here

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=m&ch%5B1%5D=e&ch%5B2%5D=t&ch%5B3%5D=r&ch%5B4%5D=o&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=0000db0c530e2024000b51e5000005dc&glyphcount=5&imageid=0&x=73&y=44

Comment: it this free font?

Comment: @lordzen - You'll get the most benefit from this site if you make at least some effort to determine the answer for yourself. A useful tool to determine whether the font may be available freely is known as Google. I believe it is a search engine.

Comment: Actually, links like that expire after a while. Best to link to the font example itself rather than WhatTheFont results.